# Why docker container exit when ENTRYPOINT ["bash"]?

Tags: docker, keycloak, docker-entrypoint

I'm setting up  jboss/keycloak container. So i need to do many quick checks (SSL certs, jdbc drivers ....) using shell commands inside it. Originaly the container starts very slowly as it runs a heavy SSO system. So I try to replace its default entrypoint ["standalone.sh"] with a light entrypoint like that:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM jboss/keycloak
# many 
# operations
# with
# files
# hire
ENTRYPOINT ["bash"] # this not works :(
```

Unfortunately the container closes with code 0 just after run. So the question is how should I set ENTRYPOINT to prevent default entrypoint and keep the container running?

** ***ADDITION*** **

I start the container using this docker-compose file

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    sso:
        build: . # <--points to Dockerfile
        environment:
            - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
            - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
        ports:
            - 8030:8080
```

Comment: If you want an interactive terminal, you need to tell Docker to pass stdin through, and invoke a terminal. What exact command are you running when you invoke that Dockerfile?

Comment: (Also, `ENTRYPOINT` is not `RUN`, and without more context it's not clear that it's the right thing; but I'd start with making sure you're passing `-i` and `-t` to `docker run`)

Comment: You can provide an alternate command after the image name, `docker run --rm -it jboss/keycloak sh`, if you want to poke around in an image with an interactive shell.

Comment: Replace with this ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]

Comment: @CharlesDuffy added doker-compose.yml

Comment: @SebastianC it not helps